# 'No thread-bound request found' in filter under Grails 2.0

Tags: spring, grails, grails-2.0

I'm developing an Grails plugin, that have filter, with code like:

```
void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, javax.servlet.FilterChain chain) {

    HttpServletRequest request = servletRequest
    HttpServletResponse response = servletResponse
    String url = request.requestURI.substring(request.contextPath.length())
    logger.debug("Processing url: $url")
    chain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse)
}
```

pretty standard Java EE filter, that extends spring's `GenericFilterBean`. And it's registered by `SpringSecurityUtils.registerFilter %NAME%, %POS%` (it's spring security extension)

After upgrading to Grails 2.0 I start getting some strange errors, on `chain.doFilter()` line:

```
No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of 
an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving 
thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this 
message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: 
In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the 
current request.
```

Notice that everything fine at `String url = request.requestURI.....` line. And displayed url is valid.

The problem that this error unpredictable :( sometimes filter is working fine, sometimes throws exception, and I can't figure out what the problem, and what I must do to fix it. Probably it depends on order of bean's initialization, but i'm not sure

---

**Update**: found that it's because of `resources` plugin. Error gone after removing this plugin. Not sure that it's a best way.

Answer (score 1):

in Grails 2.0 the webxml plugin is installed in new projects by default. It controls the order of filters in the web.xml. http://grails.org/plugin/webxml

Comment: Right - make sure you have the latest versions of webxml, resources (if you're using it) and spring-security-core to make sure that the Grails filter is before the security filter chain in web.xml.

Comment: I'm using s2.core 1.2.7 and webxml 1.4.1. More interesting thing - sometimes it's working for webxml 1.4, sometimes only for 1.4.1

Comment: Are you sure nothing in your code is throwing an exception intermittently?

Comment: @Dylan - i'm using Spring Security Core, and can't be sure that there is no exceptions at all, somewhere inside one of Security filters. But I'm sure that all of them are catched properly, if exists, and I don't see anything in logs. And it's really simple app, it's just fresh grals 2.0 app, there is nonthing that can throw any exception